# Caching refresh and update strategy inputs

Tags: database, caching, redis

I am building a Redis cache to store product data for eg

Key - value pairs as

```
key -> testKey
value [json] -> 
{
"testA" : "A",
"testB" : "B",
"testC" : "C"
}
```

Problem i am struggling with is if i get two requests to update this value for key.

request1 to change -> "testB" = "Bx"

request2 to change -> "testC" = "Cx"

How to handle inconsistancy.
As based on my understanding one request will read  above data and update only testB value and another request will update testC value because these are running in parallel and any new request is not waiting for last update in cache to propagate.

How do we maintain data consistancy with Redis ?.
I can think of locking using transaction DB in front but that will reduce latency of real time data.

Comment: "these are running in parallel" is incorrect. Redis is single-threaded and individual commands (like `HSET`) are atomic. So there is no race condition with the operations you mention.

Answer (score 0):

It based on what data structure you selected in Redis.

In your case Hash will be a good way to store all fields in your values. And use HSET command to update target fields, which can guarantee your update requests will only update a single field. And all Redis commands will be execute senquentially, so you will not have concurrency issues.

Also you can use String to store raw json data, and serialize/deserialize for each query and update. In this case you will need to consider concurrency because your read and update will not be atomic operation.(maybe a distribute lock can be the solution).